# What type of interpolation to use? For resizing a 480x395 texture into a 320x240 window

Tags: graphics, interpolation, pixel, bilinear-interpolation

ppm file that is 480 pixels wide by 395 pixels in height into a SDL window of size 320 pixels wide by 240 pixels high. I am using C++ and individual pixel coloring by 2D index in window. Any ideas are welcome
And thanks

Comment: Are you asking about choosing among {nearest, linear, and best (anisotropic)} or are you asking about something else?

Comment: yes which among nearest or linear would be most suitable in this scenario?

Comment: Short answer, you probably want _linear_.   Why don't you just try both and see which one you like better?  Do you know what those terms {nearest, linear, anisotropic} [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering#Filtering_methods) and what they [look like](https://gdbooks.gitbooks.io/legacyopengl/content/Chapter7/MinMag.html)?

Comment: try them in any decent image viewer and chose which looks best on your inputs...